# Node.js/Socket.io Chat Room Assignment & Welcome Message Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat, real-time

I'm working on a chat application using Node.js, Express, and Socket.io, designed to simulate random, spontaneous conversations. I'm facing challenges with user room assignments and message broadcasting, and I would appreciate some insights or suggestions.

**Issue Description**:

Room Assignment:

Users connect to the server, but they aren't correctly assigned to the chat rooms. They should be randomly placed in rooms with a maximum of 5 users per room.
Here's my server.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const moment = require('moment');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

let chatRooms = {};
let roomDurations = {};
let connectedUsers = {};

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user connected');

    const roomName = assignUserToRoom(socket.id);
    socket.join(roomName);
    connectedUsers[socket.id] = { room: roomName };

    console.log(`User ${socket.id} assigned to room ${roomName}`);

    socket.emit('chat message', {
        username: 'CommonRoom',
        text: 'Welcome to CommonRoom! Start chatting with random people from around the world.',
        timestamp: moment().valueOf(),
        color: "#000000"
    });

    socket.on('chat message', (data) => {
        console.log(`Received message in room ${roomName}:`, data);
        io.to(roomName).emit('chat message', data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`User ${socket.id} disconnected`);
        if (connectedUsers[socket.id]) {
            delete connectedUsers[socket.id];
        }
        removeFromRoom(socket.id, roomName);
    });
});

function assignUserToRoom(socketId) {
    for (const room in chatRooms) {
        if (chatRooms[room].length < 5) {
            chatRooms[room].push(socketId);
            return room;
        }
    }

    const newRoom = `room-${Object.keys(chatRooms).length + 1}`;
    chatRooms[newRoom] = [socketId];
    roomDurations[newRoom] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (60 * 60)) + 60;
    return newRoom;
}

function removeFromRoom(socketId, roomName) {
    chatRooms[roomName] = chatRooms[roomName].filter(id => id !== socketId);
    delete connectedUsers[socketId];

    if (chatRooms[roomName].length === 0) {
        delete chatRooms[roomName];
        delete roomDurations[roomName];
    }
}

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Welcome Message:

New users are supposed to receive a welcome message from 'CommonRoom' upon joining a chat room, but this message isn't being received or displayed.
Here's my script.js code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const socket = io(); // Connect to the WebSocket server
    
    const messageInput = document.getElementById("message-input");
    const sendButton = document.getElementById("send-button");
    const chatContainer = document.getElementById("chat-container");
    const timerValue = document.getElementById("timer-value");
    
    function appendMessage(username, message, color) {
        const chatMessage = document.createElement("div");
        chatMessage.classList.add("chat-message");
        chatMessage.innerHTML = `<span class="username" style="color: ${color};">${username}:</span> ${message}`;
        chatContainer.appendChild(chatMessage);
        chatContainer.scrollTop = chatContainer.scrollHeight;
    }
    
    function sendMessage() {
        const message = messageInput.value.trim();
        if (message !== "") {
            appendMessage("You", message, "#007bff");
            socket.emit("chat message", { username: "You", message, color: "#007bff" });
            messageInput.value = "";
        }
    }
    
    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        sendMessage();
    });
    
    messageInput.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
    
    socket.on("chat message", (data) => {
        appendMessage(data.username, data.message, data.color);
    });
    
    socket.on('room assigned', (data) => {
        console.log(`Assigned to room: ${data.room} with duration ${data.duration}`);
        startTimer(data.duration);
    });
    
    function startTimer(duration) {
        let minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
        let seconds = duration % 60;
    
        const timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
            seconds--;
            if (seconds < 0) {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 59;
            }
    
            timerValue.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
    
            if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timerInterval);
                alert('Your chat session has ended.');
                window.location.reload(); // Reload the page to start a new chat session
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

What could be causing these issues with room assignment and message broadcasting?
Are there any specific areas in my code that I should focus on to resolve these problems?
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

I have checked the console logs, and users do connect to the server, but the room assignment and welcome message functionalities are not working as expected.
I tried debugging by adding more console logs to trace the message flow, but I couldn't pinpoint the issue.

Comment: do any of your various console.log's actually get executed?

Comment: nothing appears in my console when i inspect element

Comment: I was speaking of the console.log's in the **server** where there are no elements to inspect for a start, and no console.log's in the browser anyway ... have you tried any debugging at all?

Comment: I fixed it! no worries